# How do I set the executable file attribute in .net

Tags: .net

How do I make a file executable from within a .net program running under Linux/Cygwin please? I really hope there is a better answer than "execute chmod". Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using any sort of IDE?

Comment: I need to do it from within my code. Say I am writing an installer that needs to generate a script that a user might then invoke. The script obviously needs to be executable under Cygwin/Linux for that to be easily possible.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the first time. I thought you wanted your .net program to be executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use chmod from mono.

```
   Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.chmod (string path, FilePermissions mode)
```

http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3AMono.Unix.Native.Syscall.chmod

Comment: Many thanks. I don't suppose there is a way that would also work under .net/Cygwin?

Comment: I'm not sure... but I think that if you can build mono in Cygwin you can use this same function. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19575/Building-Mono-on-Windows-the-final-battle